# I'm having trouble with this MatTableDataSource, data won't display

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble with this MatTableDataSource, data won't display:

[image: Component]
<sup>**Component**</sup>  <sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

[image: HTML]
<sup>**HTML**</sup>

Kindly help me please

Comment: Images are harder to read than text. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: do not hesitate to post your code. update this question with code instead of image or you can create a demo in https://stackblitz.com/.

Comment: Hi Guys. Sorry for the late inform. I already solve it but I have new problem. I will post it again.